# Am using google maps Api. For auto complete address text box it is showing latin characters by default i want it to be only in english

Tags: javascript, .net, google-maps, autocomplete

Hi am using google maps API in java-script. For auto complete address text box it is showing Latin characters by default i want it to be only in English (ex:Testvägen 3, Arlöv, Sweden). Thanks in advance :)